# Exception in IMultiValueConverter mentioning DependencyProperty

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to get images in the listbox supplying paths to iMultiValueConverter, doing it in the background threads:

```
<Image>
  <Image.Source>
    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource UriToBitmapConverter}">
      <MultiBinding.Bindings>
        <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" />
        <Binding Source="{Binding ImagePath}" />  
      </MultiBinding.Bindings>
    </MultiBinding>
  </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

and

```
public class UriToBitmapConverter : IMultiValueConverter 
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)    
    {
        if (values[1] == null) return null;

        BitmapImage BI= null;
        Image image = values[0] as Image;
        string mypath = values[1] as string;
        FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(mypath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((WaitCallback)delegate
                {
                    image.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal,
                        (ThreadStart)delegate
                        {
                            BI= new BitmapImage();
                            BI.BeginInit();
                            BI.StreamSource = fileStream;
                            BI.EndInit();
                            image.Source = BI;
                        });
                });
        return BI;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new Exception("The method or operation is not implemented.");
    }
}
```

I get:

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in
>   PresentationFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: A 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'Source'
>   property of type 'Binding'. A 'Binding' can only be set on a
>   DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject.

Can you tell me what am I doing wrong.

Comment: You're trying to set binding in a binding: `<Binding Source="{Binding ImagePath}" />`. Did you try setting `<Binding Path="ImagePath" />`?

Comment: If I do that I get: Error A 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'Path' property of type 'Binding'

Comment: So you replaced `<Binding Source="{Binding ImagePath}" />` with `<Binding Path="ImagePath" />` and now you get two errors?

Comment: I get by compiling : Error A 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'Path' property of type 'Binding'

Comment: ImagePath is class variable in observablecollection

Comment: It still should compile. Did you replace whole `<Binding Source="{Binding ImagePath}" />` bit with `<Binding Path="ImagePath" />`?

Comment: Thank you dkozl for being so persistent. It did fix the problem I just did something else wrong in the meantime. Cheers!